# use ssh to kill and restart all sshd processes

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a script that will

1. kill all sshd processes
2. start a new sshd process

I would like to scp this script onto a remote computer and execute it using ssh. After it executes the first step of killing all sshd, will it still get to the 2nd step of running sshd again? I'm worried because I'm running the script using ssh and ssh will die after step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Normal procedure is to stop the main sshd, with e.g. `/etc/init.d/sshd stop` or your distro's equivalent. This way, the listening daemon shuts down while existing connections go on until the clients disconnect.

If you want to upgrade/replace sshd, change any settings and restart it, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No need to `scp` it to server, just try doing this :

```
while read cmd; do ssh server "bash -c $cmd"; done < script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use cron for it?
For example:

10 * * * * /path_to_script

minute   hour   day   month   dayofweek   command

Do not forget to switch it off;)